# Bundle prebuilt Realm files from Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, realm

I've seen a few SO posts detailing how you bundle prebuilt Realm files with iOS (Obj-c/swift) and Android (Java), but I can't find any information on bundling with Xamarin from a PCL or shared project; is this possible?

I believe it would require a per-project *.realm file (e.g. copied from a single source at compile time) due to the nuances of how files are distributed in each platform, but that's a small price to pay to be able to access prebuilt data from shared code on both platforms.

My objective is to avoid an initial download process when launching the App for the first time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add your pre-populated `.realm` database to your application iOS bundle as a resource (`BundleResource` Build Action) and as a raw asset to your Android Asset directory (`AndroidAsset` Build Action).

Using the `Xamarin.Forms`-based [Journal](https://blog.xamarin.com/cross-platform-development-with-xamarin-forms-and-realm/) example from Realm you can add your populated database as a linked item to each native project and copy it at application startup.

#### Example:

In the iOS "native" project of your `Xamarin.Form` solution/application, update the `FinishedLaunching` method to copy your pre-populated database if the users database does **NOT** exist (i.e. this is the first time the application runs):

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    var prepopulated = "prepopulated.realm";
    var realmDB = "journal.realm";
    var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(documentsPath, realmDB)))
    {
        File.Copy(prepopulated, Path.Combine(documentsPath, realmDB));
    }
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    LoadApplication(new App());
    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

*Note: The same technique can be used in your other "native" projects*

*Note: A custom-written `Xamarin.Forms` dependency service is an alternative to doing it this way but the results are the same*

Since we are copying the `prepopulated.realm` to `journal.realm` within the application document directory, we can tell Realm to open this database instead of creating/using a `default.realm` one.

In the `Xamarin.Form` Journal project's `JournalEntriesViewModel.cs`, update the code to open this `journal.realm`

```
public JournalEntriesViewModel()
{
    _realm = Realm.GetInstance("journal.realm");
    Entries = _realm.All<JournalEntry>();
    AddEntryCommand = new Command(AddEntry);
    DeleteEntryCommand = new Command<JournalEntry>(DeleteEntry);
}
```

Same pre-populated database in the solution linked to different "native" projects:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great example including the screenshots! (I am one of the Realm Xamarin authors).

Comment: @AndyDent Thanks. So far loving `Realm Xamarin`, awesome work!!! Only used Realm in one large/production `Swift`-based project so far but it was amazing and the query performance over SQLite totally made that app shine. I'll dance a merry-jig if `Akavache` gets a working Realm IO provider  https://github.com/akavache/Akavache/pull/292

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, this is fantastic.  I'm still in the planning stages but I accept this is the solution!

Comment: Happy to say we are now linking to this answer as the "official" doc on bundling, from https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/0.75.0/#bundling-realm-files

Comment: @SushiHangover Thank you for your elaborated answer. Unfortunately today is my 3rd day only on all 3 - Mac, Realm and Xamarin. So, I am still figuring out what would be the correct place to put this code. So I am requesting you if you could share a GitHub link of your demo project, it would be very helpful.

Comment: This works really well for iOS, however trying the same thing in Android does not work.  Could you detail the method used for Android as well?  The line "Note: The same technique can be used in your other "native" projects" is misleading.

Comment: @E.Freitas What problem are you having on Android?

Comment: I was able to read the realm file on android by first placing the 'populated.realm' file in the PCL Resources folder, marking it as an embedded resource, then loading it with the code from this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412442/466197.  Then I was able to save it as the 'default.realm' file by using `File.WriteAllBytes(documentsPath, realmDB);` instead of `File.Copy(prepopulated, Path.Combine(documentsPath, realmDB));`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer works for Android, as opposed to the accepted answer which works only for iOS.

1. Add your prepopulated.realm file to the PCL Resources folder.  Mark it as an embedded resource by right clicking and selecting 'Build Action' > 'EmbeddedResource'.
2. Build the app.
3. From the command line run the `monodic --manifest YourApp.dll` on your dll file, which for Debug is found in `YourApp/Droid/bin/Debug`.  Find the line with `prepopulated.realm` and copy the resource string.
4. Edit your MainActivity.cs and add the following code right after the `base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);` line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to bundle a realm file on native Xamarin.Android you can use the following code. The bundled realm file can be the same name as the final realm file. Just copy the realm file to the Assets directory and make sure the build action is set as AndroidAsset.

```
var realmDB = "somerealm.realm";
var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, realmDB);
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    using (var asset = Assets.Open(realmDB))
    using (var destination = File.OpenWrite(filePath))
    {
        asset.CopyTo(destination);
    }
}
```