# How to load a font directly from an embedded resource with iText7 on .net

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I have found a method to load a font from a file using a font factory. But how should I go about loading a file directly from embedded source of dll, without creating a physical file in iText 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PdfFontFactory has following method:

> **createFont(byte[] fontProgram, boolean embedded)**
>   Creates a PdfFont instance by the bytes of the underlying font program.

So your question is basically "How do I get the byte[] from a resource in a dll", which has nothing to do with iText anymore, and which is a question that was already answered on Stack Overflow: [How to Read an embedded resource as array of bytes without writing it to disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412401/how-to-read-an-embedded-resource-as-array-of-bytes-without-writing-it-to-disk)

Comment: And which has been answered, among other places, over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412401/how-to-read-an-embedded-resource-as-array-of-bytes-without-writing-it-to-disk