# Can't Create MemoryStream using Custom File as Resource using C#

Tags: c#, stream, resources, memorystream

I am using C# and can't create a stream using a Resource.  The file is a custom file called 'test.usr' which contains a string.  The build action for it is set to None (not sure if that matters).  The error is posted below.  Does anyone know how I would correct this?

Error:  'Looks up a localized string similar to ..... Can't convert from string to int.'

```
MemoryStream certStream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.test);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412401/how-to-read-an-embedded-resource-as-array-of-bytes-without-writing-it-to-disk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I generate a stream from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1879395/how-do-i-generate-a-stream-from-a-string)

Comment: Use somthing like `MemoryStream certStream  = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("xxx.yyy.Resources.test.usr");`

Comment: @NaDeRStar it has a red squiggly line that says 'Cannot implicitly convert System.IO.Stream to System.IO.MemoryStream'

Comment: @NaDeRStar  MemoryStream certStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Resources.test.usr");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Properties.Resources.test` is a `string`. [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) does not have a constructor that accepts strings. It can accept an array of bytes though. So you can convert the `string` to an array of bytes:

```
MemoryStream certStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Properties.Resources.test));
```

Comment: One other option I did that worked was to change the FileType of the resource from String to Binary